# Understanding binomial GLMM with three fixed factors

Tags: r, categorical-data, interaction, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am analyzing my data using a generalized linear mixed model in R. My design has three categorical variables:

- `proficiency` (three levels: Chinese vs English vs Japanese),a between subject effect, that is, three groups of participants
- `function` (two levels: component vs radical), a between-subject effect
- `position` (five levels: left, right,top,bottom, inside), a within-subject effect
- and the dependent variable `response` is binomial (0 or 1)

I model these three categorical variables as fixed effects while `subject`(the participants) and `item`(the experimental trail) are random effects. The R code looks like this:

```
glmm <- glmer(formula=response~proficiency*function*position+
                 (1|item)+(1|subject), 
              family=binomial, data=data1,
          control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

My questions are:

1. I would like to see the interaction between these three IVs (proficiency*function*position). Is the R code suitable? How could I get the $p$-value of this interaction?
2. How do I interpret the results? Since the model sets English, component and bottom as the baseline levels by default, I cannot find the comparison of the baseline. So the question is, how could I do the comparison between different levels?
3. After looking though the websites, somebody suggested that by `relevel` the baseline then can find the results of different levels, but I found that the estimate and the $p$-value change by releveling the baseline.
4. Somebody suggested using the `glht` function, but the output is general linear hypotheses rather than generalized linear mixed model. Does that influence the validity of the results?

Comment: Be aware that asking for / about code is off topic here, but your statistical questions can be addressed.

Comment: Clarification questions about your experimental design: how are different factors nested inside each other? Which levels of the fixed factors does one subject experience? What is an "item"? Which levels o the fixed factors does one "item" go with?

Comment: @gung thank you for your edition which makes the questions more clearly!

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for your advice! It is a psycholinguistic study! Factors are independent I think, I am not sure. The first factor language is a between-subject variable which means that there are three groups participated in the experiment. And the other two factors are within-subject variables. So the item here, like other linguistic study, is about the experimental trails. and 5*2 different kind of items here which would be repeated several times. Each participants should accept 5*2 different materials. This is a 3*5*2 design.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. I would like to see the interaction between these three IVs (`proficiency*function*position`). Is the R code suitable? How could I get the p-value of this interaction?

The simplest approach is to do a likelihood ratio test between the model with and without this interaction;

```
glmm_noint <- update(glmm, . ~ . - proficiency:function:position)
anova(glmm_noint,glmm)
```

`drop1(glmm,test="Chisq")` should also work; you may also be interested in `afex::mixed(glmm)`

> 2. How do I interpret the results? Since the model sets English, component and bottom as the baseline levels by default, I cannot find the comparison of the baseline. So the question is, how could I do the comparison between different levels?  (For example, English.component.bottom vs English.radical.bottom, since English, component and bottom were set as the baseline, I could not find them in the output of the model.)

There are several different packages (`lsmeans`, `effects`, `multcomp`) that are designed for *post hoc* computation of expected values for particular levels and/or comparisons between particular levels.

> 3. After looking though the websites, somebody suggested that by relevel the baseline then can find the results of different levels, but I found that the estimate and the p-value change by releveling the baseline.

This is inevitable. The main effects are *defined* in terms of the baseline levels of the other parameters in the model (for example, the "main effect of French" is defined as "the effect of switching from English (baseline level) to French *when the other predictors are at their baseline levels* [component, bottom]").  The only time when the results will *not* depend on the factor definitions is in a model with no interactions (and a perfectly orthogonal design).

> 4. Somebody suggested using the glht function, but the output is general linear hypotheses rather than generalized linear mixed model. Does that influence the validity of the results?

No. `glht` should work. Most forms of extensions of the linear model (e.g. generalized linear models and generalized linear mixed models) rely on the ability to make inferences, at least approximately, based on the underlying linear parameterizations.

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanations! I have another question that when I conduct a glht analysis, it comes out with the warning that "In RET$pfunction("adjusted", ...):Completion with error>abseps". Is it acceptable? If not, what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for all your explanations! Now, I wonder can I use Anova in car package to get the main and interaction effect for this model? That is, could Anova be used for GLMM. Because I found that the results between anova (in R) and Anova (in car) are not identical.